# Why can I not assign Symbol.hasInstance onto a function?

Tags: javascript, symbols

I have the following code:

```
function A() {
}

A[Symbol.hasInstance] = function(i) {return true}
```

It fails with an error in my Webpack+Babel environment:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'Symbol(Symbol.hasInstance)' of function 'function A() {}'
```

Why?

Comment: Related: It looks like `Symbol.hasInstance` isn't implemented in anything except for Firefox 50 right now.

Comment: @naomik `Symbol.hasInstance` seems to be implemented in Chrome (I'm on Chrome stable v51). I can see it in the console. `function A() {}; A[Symbol.hasInstance] = function() {}` works in the console. Maybe this is a problem with Webpack/Babel transpilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because the property descriptor for `Function.prototype[Symbol.hasInstance]` has `{writable: false}`, which makes it not possible to assign in that manner. The JS engine looks up the `Function.prototype[Symbol.hasInstance]` descriptor, sees `writable: false`, then forbids the assignment even if it is being assigned on a leaf object of the prototype type rather than on the original object where the property was found, or in other words, the `writable: false` property is prototypically inherited even though the property does not yet exist on the leaf-most object of the prototype chain where we are trying to assign the value.

To get around the issue, we can use `Object.defineProperty`, which works just fine:

```
function A() {
}

Object.defineProperty(A, Symbol.hasInstance, {
  value: function(i) {return true}
})
```